# how can i get the location of the player along a specific axis during play mode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my player runs forward during play time so what i want to do is store his current position along a specific axis lets say z in a variable inside the update function and use that position elsewhere. i also want to know what kind of datatype we have to use to store such value like the current position of player on the z axis if doing so is even possible. i saw this code somewhere:-

```
var playerPos:Vector3 = playerObject.transform.position;
```

but idk how its working if it is in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close but the current syntax in your code is for Javascript.

You use `transform.position` to get the position of all axis. `transform.position` returns a `Vector3` and that `Vector3` contains all axis for your GameObject position.`Vector3` has `x`, `y` and `z` properties which are all `float` datatype.

**ACCESSING THE POSITION**:

Assuming that `playerObject` is the name of your GameObject, below is an example of how to access each individual axis.

To get the X axis

```
float x = playerObject.transform.position.x;
```

To get the Y axis

```
float y = playerObject.transform.position.y;
```

To get the Z axis

```
float z = playerObject.transform.position.z;
```

You can also get the position **once** and store it into a `Vector3` variable then access each individual axis from there:

To get the All axis (x,y,z)

```
Vector3 playerPos = playerObject.transform.position;
float x = playerPos.x;
float y = playerPos.y;
float z = playerPos.z;
```

**MODIFYING THE POSITION**:

Modifying the position is different from accessing the it. You can access like this

```
float x = playerObject.transform.position.x;
```

but **cannot** change the `x` like this:

```
playerObject.transform.position.x = 6f;
```

You must create a new `Vector3`, modify the axis you want to (`x`, `y` and `z`), then change the `transform.position` variable with that new variable(`Vector3`).

It should something like this:

```
 Vector3 newPos = playerObject.transform.position;
 newPos.x = 5f;
 newPos.y = 4f;
 newPos.z = 3f;
 playerObject.transform.position = newPos;
```

My suggestion to you is to always use the [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html). It shows you what each property or method returns. This will prevent you from asking such question like this. For example, the [Transform.position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) returns `Vector3`.

When you click on that `Vector3`, you will see many other variables you can access from it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet is in javascript.

The player position is a `Vector3` where the single values (x, y and z) are floats. So this will give you the single values:

```
Vector3 pos = playerObject.transform.position;
float x = pos.x;
float y = pos.y;
float z = pos.x;
```

This can be shortened, but for the purpose of demonstration I did it like this. Obviously you need to get the `playerObject` in some way.

Doing something like this is like the very basics of coding in unity, so if you aren't familiar with that I'd recommend you have a look on the unity tutorials here -> https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials